# Styled Components - Share CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have the following style:

```
export const oneLine = styled.style`
    white-space: nowrap;
`
```

I am trying to use it inside of a styled component like this:

```
const Foo = styled.div`
    ${oneLine}
    ...
`
```

However, the style is not being applied. Why is this?

Other answers have mentioned to use `styled.css`, but that no longer exists.

Comment: what do you mean "that no longer exists"? [`css`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css) is still mentioned in the docs

Comment: Oh, I see. The Stack Overflow answers I saw said to use `styled.css`, but it turns out I need to use just `css`. Either that, or I misread.

Comment: if you imported `import * as styled from 'styled-components';` usage would like exactly as you mentioned(`styled.css\`...`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `styled.style` use `css`:

```
import { css } from 'styled-components'

export const oneLine = css`
    white-space: nowrap;
`
```

Other file:

```
const Foo = styled.div`
    ${oneLine}
    ...
`
```

Comment: Can u pass props to ${oneLine}?